# Show that $\left(\forall \ x \in G\right)\left(\forall \ y \in G\right)\ x*y*y*x=y*x*x*y$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $\left(G,\ *\right)$ be a group such that:

$$\left(\forall \ x \in G\right)\ x*x*x=e$$

where $e$ is the identity element of $\left(G,\ *\right)$

I need to prove the following statement:

$$\left(\forall \ x \in G\right)\left(\forall \ y \in G\right)\ x*y*y*x=y*x*x*y$$

Any hints how to get started?

Comment: $(xy^{-1})^3=e \Rightarrow xy^{-1}x=yx^{-1}y$.

Comment: So $x$ has order $3$, correct? and the same is true for $y \in G:$, $y$ has order 3.

Comment: @amWhy more precisely all elements have order 1 or 3.

Comment: Of course.  We are taking $e$ to be of order 1. So all elements besides $e$ have order three; the identity element $e$ is unique.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have $a^3=e$ for any $a$. Let $a=xy^2$ so

\begin{eqnarray*}
x y^2 x y^2 x y^2 =e.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now post multiply by $yx^2y$.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that $x\ast x=x^{-1}$, $y\ast y=y^{-1}$.  We also have $(xy^{-1})^3=e$.